# Reorder Array of objects Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Array of object

Input:

```
[
 {id:1,order:1},
 {id:2,order:null},
 {id:3,order:0},
 {id:4,order:null},
 {id:5,order:3}
]
```

Output:

```
[
 {id:3,order:0},
 {id:1,order:1},
 {id:2,order:null},
 {id:5,order:3},
 {id:4,order:null}
]
```

Considering model

```
Item(int id,int? Order)
```

By default the order is null and these positions are to be maintained and object having orders are to be moved up or down.

Comment: whats meaning of order:null

Comment: There is no value assigned

Comment: You should explain how do you want to re-order this, if order: null, what should the re-order algorithm does

Comment: Comment added .

Comment: Your desire for "these positions are to be maintained" if `order` is `null` is ill-defined.  Exactly what does that mean?  In your example, `{id:4,order:null},` starts at index 3, follows `id:3` and precedes `id:5`, but you want it to end up at index 4 and follow `id:5`.

Comment: Your example does not add up with your description text. None of your nulls is preserved as ordered before in your example.

Comment: Basically only the objects with order should be moved up or down in the position of the index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the array is of type Map -

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => a['order'].compareTo(b['order']));
```

Or this if it is holding Item class with an order attribute

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((Item a, Item b) => a.order.compareTo(b.order));
```

Note - You can remove items with null order before running the sort.

Example

```
arrayOfObjects.removeWhere((item)=> item.order == null);
```

Comment: We cannot use compare if there's null.Also we need the ones with null also in the array as that's the old location and doesn't have to be changed.

Comment: If you don't want to rearrange the nulls then simply store their index and after sorting insert them in their old indexes

Comment: Can share the example for the above expected output

Answer (score 0):

The double Iterations are based on the length of the array to handle the nulls.
Solution

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Item {
   int? _id;
   int? _order;

  Item({int? id, int? order}) {
    this._id = id;
     this._order = order;
  }

  int? get id => _id;
  set id(int? id) => _id = id;
  int? get order => _order;
  set order(int? order) => _order = order;

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _id = json['id'];
   _order = json['order'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this._id;
    data['order'] = this._order;
    return data;
  }
}


List<Item> reorder(List<Item> it){

  var tempData = it;
  tempData.forEach((_){
  tempData.forEachIndexed((index,val){
  ///Remove original and replace
   var ind = val.order;
  if(ind!=null){
  
   ///Check if it is at the Proper Position
    if (index == ind) {
      return;
    }

     var first = it.removeAt(index);
     it.insert(ind as int, first);
  }
    
  });
 });

  return it; 
}

void main() {
  var list = [
    Item(id: 1, order: 1),
    Item(id: 3, order: 2),
    Item(id: 2, order: 7),
    Item(id: 4, order: null),
    Item(id: 5, order: null),
    Item(id: 6, order: null),
    Item(id: 7, order: 6),
  Item(id: 8, order: 4)
  ];

  list.forEach((it) => print('${it.id} ->${it.order}'));


  var first = reorder(list);


  print('\n');
  first.forEach((it) => print('${it.id} ->${it.order}'));
  ///Stack List
}
```